# My email server is classed as a spammer by hotmail

Tags: email-server, mx-record, email

I created an email server hosted at IP 65.75.241.26 with domain www.softmail.me using which I can send and receive emails from all users and I don't have problem with any other except hotmail. That my emails are moving to Junk bin of hotmail. How to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You server/domain is probably missing some configurations that helps prove that you are not a spammer. Other mail servers have various checks in place to qualify what is spam and what is not. Many of these spam checks add details to the headers of an e-mail message which could clue you into what Hotmail may be flagging your e-mails on. I would recommend sending yourself an e-mail to a Hotmail address from your server and read through the headers (look for an option to view the message source when you have an e-mail message open).

A few examples of configurations that will cause such problems include the following:

- IP address to your mail server is deemed as being dynamically addressed. Ensure your e-mail server has a static IP address assigned to it
- Your IP address may not have a [reverse DNS entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup)
- Your IP address and/or domain may have been flagged for spamming in the past. Consider checking the various black lists out there to ensure your domain & IP address are in good standing. A site such as http://www.blacklistalert.org/ is a good tool for this. Keep in mind that Hotmail is a very big mail service provider and likely has their own spam protection rules and lists being maintained. The headers may reveal more information about this.
- Do a check on your mail server to ensure all tests pass at http://www.mxtoolbox.com/ . All though this isn't a definitive test for Hotmail, it may point out possible problems on how your mail server was configured.
- Ensure [SPF records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) are created for your domain.

Comment: Spf AND senderid are important

Comment: Hah! Good call. I just edited that in at the same time as you left the comment.

Comment: +1 for checking headers. If someone can't do this or don't understand why it's important then IMHO they shouldn't be operating an email server.

Comment: How about adding check-auth@verifier.port25.com; send an email there to test spf/senderid/spamassassin/dkim/domainkeys